# Did Gohan start with all the power he has?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

In *Dragon Ball Z*, Gohan was born with a lot of hidden power. On two separate occasions, Guru and Elder Supreme Kai used rituals to awaken his hidden potential. His ascended Saiyan form used against Cell could also be thought of as an awakening of his true potential. Does this mean that Gohan was born with all the power he has as Ultimate Gohan? Or are there power multipliers or something at work here? Did his potential perhaps change due to him training? Or was the potential he used against Majin Buu truly always within him?

Answer (score 1):

Gohan was born with a very high power level, which I believe was compared to Broly's (don't really remember that part) and because of this he was capable of doing things that took other saiyans a ton of training to achieve but because he had slacked off on his training, he never seemed to get any stronger nor does he seem to have the drive/battlelust of saiyans so he eventually got left behind by other characters. So yes, he was born with high potential and that potential was unlocked but beyond that... he lack the saiyans drive for battle, and the more saiyans fight, the stronger they become... Gohan human nature apparently dominates his saiyan's side...